# Why can't I catch Pokémon?

Tags: pokemon-go

Every time I try and catch a Pokémon, e.g. when I click the Pokémon the first time to go into the catching screen, the app will shut off. It has been like this for at least 24 hours now. How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you contacted Niantic's tech support? https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/222061187-Report-a-bug

Comment: I also have this. For the last few releases, whenver they release, they turn the AR (camera back on), which causes Pokemon Go to crash. Usually I swipe the app from recents, tap a Pokemon, and I have about a quarter of a second to turn off AR before the crash. If I manage, I'm crash free until the next update a month later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are affected by the Pokemon Go Android 0.55.0 bug. 
There are a lot of reports that on this version people have problems with seeing their trainer page, incl. their buddy. Some people even reported their app crashing when they try to catch a pokemon.

Link: [Link, in the comments more players report crashing when catching pokemon as well.](https://pokemongohub.net/new-android-bug-0-55-0-crashing-pokemon-go/)

Answer (score 0):

You should delete the app and download it again. If that doesn't work, check if there's any corrupted data on the phone. You should also check if any other app is damaging Pokemon Go's performance. If all else fails, try to avoid playing the app or downloading it again. That will make you not care about the problem anymore, making this question useless (lol).